# Turn led on when both switches are pressed

Tags: c, arm

I'm trying to turn the led on in my tiva launchpad(tm4c123).

Current code :

```
while (1)       
    {
        switch(GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R & 0x11) // 0x11 = 10001
        {
            case 0x00: //both switches are pressed
            {
                GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R = 0x02; // turn on the red led
                break;
            }
            case 0x01: //SW1 is pressed, SW2 is not pressed
            {
                GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R = 0x04; // turn on the blue led
                break;
            }
            case 0x10: //SW2 is pressed, SW1 is not pressed
            {
                GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R = 0x08; // turn on the green led
                break;
            }
            default:
                GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Without this two lines of code, this is what happens :

- The board start with the green led on.
- When I press both or only SW2 nothing happens.
- When I press SW1 the red led turn on.

Could someone explain to me why?

```
GPIO_PORTF_LOCK_R = 0x4C4F434B;
GPIO_PORTF_CR_R = 0x1F;
```

Comment: I don't know that platform, but might `_R` refer to a read-only register?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read your switches on your tiva launchpad like this:

```
SW1 = GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R&0x10;     // read PF4 into SW1
SW2 = GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R&0x01;     // read PF0 into SW2
```

Then you can check the status of those inputs and make decisions.

```
if (!SW1 && !SW2) { // both pressed
    GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R = 0x04;
} else if (!SW1) { // SW1 pressed
    GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R = 0x02;
} else if (!SW2) { // SW2 pressed
    GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R = 0x08;
} else { // neither
    GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R = 0x00;
}
```

If you look at the TM4C123GH6PM [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/spms376e/spms376e.pdf), on page 205, it says;

> Protection is provided for the GPIO pins that can be used as the four
>   JTAG/SWD pins

If you check the *signal tables* on page 1329, you will see that PF0 ,where one of your switches is connected to, is one of them. So you need to unlock it.

On page 684, it says

> Writing 0x4C4F.434B to the GPIOLOCK register unlocks the GPIOCR
>   register.